# Julia notebook in win64

Tags: julia

I followed the instructions in https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("IJulia")
using IJulia
notebook()
```

After creating an IJulia notebook, it gets stuck at "In[*]" trying to calculate 1+1. I created a python notebook and the same code runs fine. The Julia prompt is also able to run this calculation.

Starting jupyter from the Anaconda console and running the same IJulia notebook does not show any error either.

The Julia kernel takes about 10 s to start, which seems to be a long time compared to the python kernel.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/693. IJulia isn't working under Julia v0.7+ yet (at least on Windows). People are presumably working hard to fix this, so let's hope this issue vanishes soon.

Note, the link above contains a temporary fix, if you are willing to try.